# Integration error with Cocoapods and XCode5

Tags: cocoapods, xcode5

When building my project in the new XCode5, I receive the following warning: **Pods-App was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods-App.a' because its architectures 'i386' didn't contain all required architectures 'x86_64'**.

Answer (score 28):

To fix that, select the **Pods** project in the left menu, then under the **targets** section select the **Pods-#YourAppName#** target and in the **build settings** click on the **Architectures** and press delete so it goes to the default option (Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s). More information can be found in this [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/1352).

Comment: there is no Pods-#MyAppName on the targets and all the other targets are already on the standard architectures

Comment: The standard architectures aren't necessarily just 32-bit (armv7, armv7s). My standard included 64-bit (arm64). I'm guessing one of my pods must not have been 64-bit compatible, so using my standard archs wasn't working.

For my **Pods** ***Project***, I made mine 32-bit by selecting `32-bit Intel (i386)` from **Architectures**. Then for each Pod **target**, I did the same as you and set their archs to the default option (which was now 32-bit for me, because of the arch change for the pod project)

Answer (score 18):

Non of the other answers worked for me.

What eventually solved it for me is to make sure `Build Active Architecture Only` is set to Yes for Debug and No for Release in my app's xcodeproj file.

Also, because I have custom configurations, I had to add the following to the Podfile:

```
xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj', 'MyDebugConfiguration' => :debug, 'MyReleaseConfiguration' => :release
```

Comment: "What eventually solved it for me is to make sure Build Active Architecture Only is set to Yes for Debug and No for Release in my app's xcodeproj file."  This did the trick

Comment: THANKS A LOT: Worked fot me without the custom configuration. In Build Active Architecture Only ser Debug - YES and Relase - NO.

Comment: This also worked for me. It's really odd that most answers in stackoverflow tells you to do otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the blog post [here](http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-xcode-5-project-build-settings-for-architectures-and-arm64-support/), it will do the work.

> To make your Applications compatible for iPhone 5s and older models (till iPhone 3Gs running iOS6), select the following option for your architectures – “Standard Architectures – armv7, armv7s”. Do not select the option that says “Standard Architectures (including 64 bit)…”. Since the Arm instruction sets are backward compatible, any application compiled for armv7s will also run on the iPhone 5s or the iPhone 5c.
>
> ARCHS = armv7 armv7s
>
> For valid architectures in the build settings, you can specify arm64,
>   armv7, armv7s.
>
> VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64

Comment: Just as a rule it is generally wise to add the relevant information from the reference to the answer to reduce the likelihood of link rot infecting the answers usefulness.

Answer (score 7):

env:

- CocoaPods v0.24.0
- Xcode 5 from App Store

Add the following at the end of your Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project "pods", set "build active architecture only" to NO for debug.

Above solution is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgraded one of my projects to Xcode 6 and experienced this problem. To fix it, I changed the Base SDK of the Pods project to a real one (previously it was like unknown SDK).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The warning suggested that the pod library was not included and as a result, the app failed to finish compiling. (It complained about a missing header file that was part of a Pod dependency).

If you are experiencing the same compilation issue, you might be able to resolve it with the following:

1. Select Pods project in the workspace
2. Select Pods project to
   access Pods project-wide settings
3. Go to Build Settings
4. Search
   for 'Build Active Architecture Only'
5. Set to 'NO'

This seemed to work for me, but YMMV.